# how do I convince my parents not to break the law against me?

Tags: health

My parents are trying to act out malpractice against me. Basically they defame my mental health as much as possible, and they invented a rule in the house to coerce me into doing their demands.

Essentially if I don't see a psychiatrist like they want me to, they will kick me out. In fact my dad said he would literally take each and every one of my assets and throw them out the window( mind you, he is the mental one not me).

The reason i don't want to sue this right off the bat. Is because I would rather they seek help instead of damaging themselves like they are doing so right now.

Anyhow, before I even try any of that. I'm trying to talk my parents out of their sadism. What are effective methods of doing so?

Comment: Laws vary widely. What country are you in? If the US, what state? How old are you?

Comment: 26 in Texas. united states

Comment: Are they picking a psychiatrist or can you comply by going to one you select? Are they promising to pay for the psychiatrist? And are you, or can you soon be, self supporting financially?

Comment: 3 years ago she was stealing money from a joint account ( she fought the banker and violated my trust) and i closed it but it was too late to recover the stolen money.

She then said to me the following " Any money that's left in that account ( about $3000) I will utilize on a psychiatrist)

Comment: I'm a unemployed professional software engineer. I would need to somehow borrow roughly $3000 to survive the first month if I evict myself in such fashion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you comfortable disclosing what your "mental health" issues are? If it's what I think it is, you may have options or be able to find support.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch that's what a cop would say, just stay out of it, let them eat each other. And I kinda see your point though: The specific question at the bottom does not really relate remotely to any legal question. But, for the furtherance of justice, should we not to read the question into the question that will help justice to prevail? There should be remedy for every wrong. Maybe the harm they caused him/her/them is such they couldn't even formulate the right question not having a brief moment of clarity. He asked this question here, let those willing and able answer as they can.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I vote to keep it. I hope someone can help him/her/them.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an actual lease under which you reside at your parents' place, they must abide by the terms of that lease – presumably that sets the rent that you pay and states how long the lease is good for, Otherwise, if you're just living there, and have been living there for some time, then the courts may [treat you as a month-to-month tenant](https://texaslawhelp.org/article/roommates). That means that they can end the tenancy with 30 days notice. Or, they can initiate an eviction proceeding. The less optimal outcome is that the court may treat you as a house guest, in which case no formal eviction proceeding is necessary. One way or the other, it is illegal to physically give a person the heave-ho from their residence, even if it is a family member. One recourse then is to hire an attorney to persuade your parents of at least that aspect of the law, if it is really in doubt.

[This gent](https://attorneybrianwhite.com/blog/how-do-parents-evict-their-adult-children/) addresses the matter for parents whose children have moved back home. He also mentions hiring a mediator, which could put the situation on a clearer legal ground. As for psychiatrists, anybody can see a psychiatrist; and anybody is free to hire a lawyer to try to force another person to see a psychiatrist. The prospects of getting a court order to force a child or a parent to see a psychiatrist because they are at loggerheads over some matter is extremely remote. The courts only force psychiatric treatment in extreme cases (e.g. threats of violence, actual delusions).

Comment: @@user6726 God bless your heart!